# How to get closest value of span on click by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, closest

When a user clicks on a link. I am trying to find the closest span value by class and then get that classes text. Currently it is just returning empty text:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="plan recommended">
    <div class="recommended-badge"><span>DOUBLE DATA</span></div>

    <div data-equalizer-listener="plan-heading" class="plan-header">
        <div class="prices">
            <div class="col total">
                <div class="price"><sup>$</sup> <span class="amount">85</span> <span class="caption">per month</span></div>
            </div>

            <p class="min-payment">Min. Total Cost is $2,040 over 24 months.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="features">
        <div class="feature included_data PO_Included_Data standard first" data-equalizer-selector="PO_Included_Data" style="height: 247px;">
            <div class="description"><span class="highlight-text">28GB TOTAL DATA</span><br>
                <span class="legal">Includes 14GB + 14GB bonus data for 24 mths<br>
New and recontracting services only<br>
Offer ends 15/04/18<br>
$10 per extra 1GB</span></div>

            <div class="more-data-info hide" data-information="included-data"><strong>Data Pool -</strong> Combine any of our latest My Plan Plus (including SIM Only) and My Mobile Broadband Plus plans on the one bill to pool and share the data.</div>

            <div><a href="#" class="more-data-link" data-information="included-data" tabindex="0">more</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and my javascript

So when someone clicks on the `a href` with the `class="more-data-link"` I want to find the span with the `class="amount"` and get its text

```
$(".more-data-link").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = $(this).closest('plan-header').find('.price').find('.amount').text();
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: `closest('.plan-header')` You missed a dot :)

Comment: thanks mate. tried that just shows as blank

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Still won't work, as `.plan-header` is not an ancestor of `.price`/`.amount`, it is a sibling of an ancestor

Comment: @LGSon That is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ When a 99k user only state that, one will assume that was all to it...

Comment: @LGSon Sometimes it may be true. Not in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9omhzp3z/55/)

```js
$(".more-data-link").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = $(this).closest('.plan.recommended').find('.plan-header .price .amount').text();
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<div class="plan recommended">
    <div class="recommended-badge"><span>DOUBLE DATA</span></div>
    <div data-equalizer-listener="plan-heading" class="plan-header">
        <div class="prices">
            <div class="col total">
                <div class="price"><sup>$</sup> 
                    <span class="amount">85</span>    
                    <span class="caption">per month</span></div>
                </div>
               <p class="min-payment">Min. Total Cost is $2,040 over 24 months.</p>
            </div>
     </div>
    <div class="features">
        <div class="feature included_data PO_Included_Data standard first" data-equalizer-selector="PO_Included_Data" style="height: 247px;">
            <div class="description"><span class="highlight-text">28GB TOTAL DATA</span><br>
                <span class="legal">Includes 14GB + 14GB bonus data for 24 mths<br>New and recontracting services only<br>Offer ends 15/04/18<br>$10 per extra 1GB</span>
            </div>
            <div class="more-data-info hide" data-information="included-data">
             <strong>Data Pool -</strong> Combine any of our latest My Plan Plus (including SIM Only) and My Mobile Broadband Plus plans on the one bill to pool and share the data.
            </div>
            <div>
             <a href="#" class="more-data-link" data-information="included-data" tabindex="0">more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to select parent (plan recommended) class and then find its child...

Comment: Thanks @Sarvan I didn't know you had to chain the classes. This worked!

Comment: Always welcome. If you use chain like that it will search one by one inside of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking a solution without jquery (the logic inside the click event is the same as described by Sarvan Kumar):

```
window.onload = function(){
    for(var tL=document.querySelectorAll('.more-data-link'), i=0, j=tL.length; i<j; i++){
        tL[i].onclick = function(){
            var tE = function fA(e){return !e || (e.className && e.className.indexOf('plan') !== -1 && e.className.indexOf('recommended') !== -1) ? e && e.querySelector('.amount') : fA(e.parentNode)}(this);
            console.log(tE ? tE.textContent : '404')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I check your script and find some error in it, use `innerHtml` in place of `text()` and `closest('plan-header')` should be `closest('.plan-header')`. but may be you not get the proper result because it will search in parents div not subling check link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp

you can use the simplest and best way to do same by creating the attribute of the more-data-link and save value of amount in it and use the following code.

```
$(".more-data-link").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
var x = $(this).attr('amount');
console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(".more-data-link").on("click", function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
      var x = $(this).closest('.plan-header').find('.amount').text(); 
      console.log(x); 
 });
```

Fixed it. You don't need to use the second find and you missed a dot

Comment: this just returns blank